# Return a median value in excel where there are multiple rows of data

Tags: excel

In Excel how do I return a median value for a set of data where there are multiple rows and columns? I have a set of data where the first column contains a reference number and the second column contains a list of readings over a number of days. How do I calculate the median value for each reference number using a formula?

```
number  volume
1   3072
1   2304
1   2016
1   2496
1   2144
1   2528
1   3312
1   3360
1   2976
1   2768
1   2688
1   3040
1   3008
1   2560
2   574
2   574
2   574
2   574
2   576
2   574
2   575
2   574
2   576
2   574
2   574
2   574
2   574
2   574
3   2880
3   2880
3   2912
3   2976
3   1536
3   288
3   2976
3   2944
3   2880
3   1536
3   2976
3   1536
3   2880
3   2880
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2268
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
4   2267
5   800
5   800
5   1984
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   416
5   1984
6   800
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   800
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
6   832
```

The reference number is Column A and the reading is Column B. In this example I have used just six reference numbers but my real data has several hundred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the *array formula*:

```
=MEDIAN(IF($A$2:$A$83=ROWS($1:1),$B$2:$B$83))
```

pick a cell, enter the formula and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A:A=1,B:B))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

For a non CSE Array formula, one entered normally, if you have 2010 or later then use this:

```
=AGGREGATE(17,6,(B:B/(A:A=1)),2)
```

Where `1` is the reference number.  You can make it dynamic by adding a cell reference, so as that cell changes so will the answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the formatting correction Scott and thank you for your response. However I am looking for the MEDIAN and not the AVERAGE.

Comment: @CarlPitcher sorry my bad, saw Median and read Mean.  See edit.